# Calling JavaScript function in between the URL Query String

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to call one javascript function in between my query string in the following manner but its not working......Can anybody point out whether i am doin it correctly or not?
My motive is to remove special characters(#,& etc.) from one of the parameters(appName) in my query string............plz help!!

```
<a target="_self" onmouseout="hideTooltip()" onmouseover="showTooltip(event,'click on the name for additional details');return false" class="tip" href='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.jsp?page=myhome&type=details&appName=javascript:escape('<%=adMetricsVO.getApplicationName()%>')&Id=<%=bean.getID()%>'><%= bean.getName()%></a>
```

Comment: You cannot run JavaScript inside the `href` attribute -- it's not a JavaScript-aware attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not going to work because the Javascript interpreter won't be involved with the ordinary "click" behavior of the element. In other words, Javascript is never going to *see* that "href" value.

To make that work, you could either escape the application name on the server, or else put the URL together in a separate piece of Javascript that you wire up to the window "load" event, or something like that.

Alternatively you could have the "click" handled by a Javascript handler that makes the URL and reloads the page.

Answer (score 2):

That's very wrong.  (and impossible to do as you're attempting)

You should escape the `getApplicationName()` on the server.
You need to URL-encode it, *then* attribute-encode it.